# How should I model this data so it is easy to query and plays nice with elastic search indices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, elasticsearch, data-modeling

**Models:**

Account

- This is used to store the login credentials of anyone in the system
- It is a devise model and has one custom field 'role' to handle authorization
- An account is linked to someone (uniquely) in the system

Employee

- This uses an account to login and contains an account_id FK

Client

- This uses an account to login and contains an account_id FK

**Relations:**

It is setup such that an account `has_one :employee` and `has_one :client`.

An employee and client each `belongs_to :account`.

**Queries:**

I would like to be able to answer questions like:

*"Show me all unlinked employee accounts"*

- This was solved by this raw query:

  `find_by_sql("select * from accounts where id not in (select account_id from employees)")`
- The above implementation is going to get ugly when I want to show all unlinked accounts across many tables which is something I'll certainly want to do.

**Alternative solution:**

Should I change the setup so I have both an employee_id and client_id in the account table instead?

Then it would be easy to just check for nils in each FK to get a list of employee-linked, client-linked or completely unlinked accounts. The FKs could be indexed in elasticsearch too.

There is a problem with this approach though, if I add another thing like customer I would need to add a customer_id into the ES index. Would I have to rebuild my entire index then?

**Alternative solution B:**

This is basically the same as the above alternative solution but make Account polymorphic and then it is "accountable", which can be applied to both employees and clients. I heard I should avoid using polymorphic associations though because it's a relation smell?

**Thoughts?**

Also on the employee index view I would want to filter/count employees who are not linked to an account with a facet. Is this going to be a problem with any of the solutions? How would this be setup?

What do you think is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least at this point first solution doesn't sound bad(maybe You have more info than Ypu have gave us :) ).

I don't see any terrible complexities You seem facing with SQL queries. Maybe You have chosen a bad example. Your `find_by_sql` query can be written using OUTER JOIN like this:

```
Account.joins( "LEFT OUTER JOIN employees ON employees.account_id = accounts.id" ).where("clients.id" => nil)
```

Alternatively:

```
Account.where("NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM clients c where c.account_id = accounts.id )")
```

These queries are basically the same (they generate same query plan).

If queries get really complex, Postgres has a good means to organise those - called [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).
There is even gem that provides a neat DSL to use them:

http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2013/09/06/postgres_ext-adds-rank-and-common-table-expressions.html

Comment: I don't have anything extra as of right now, but I thought those queries would get ugly if I introduced new models that use account.

Your query atm is only dealing with employees on accounts but what happens when you want to filter clients or customers, or a combination of the 2. It would start to get really unwieldly.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You can separate those by scopes and combine together in one single. That's the strategy I used when I needed to aggregate data and specify a lot of conditions.

Comment: That sounds reasonable and since you can import methods to elastic search it should work fine for indexing it in ES too? I thought I would be stuck having to write ES queries but it would have been a problem since you can't really join then.

Comment: At my work we supply ES JSON built from complex queries that are composition of several queries. Also do You use (re)tire - https://github.com/karmi/retire ? If You have some complex custom index for ES You can extract to separate Ruby service object like we do it.

Comment: I am using retire yeah, I'm also very new to ES. Just getting started with it. Would you mind gisting a quick sample of how I could incorporate the result of calling a scope into a model's index?